# Why does twisting/braiding strands of string into a rope make it stronger?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, continuum-mechanics, string

I am currently doing an experiment where I am measuring the force required to extend two parallel pieces of string to a set distance. The independent variable I'm changing is the number of times the two pieces of strings twists with each other.

I got a pretty good positive linear graph but I don't know how to mathematically explain it with Physics. I know it has something to do with the string becoming shorter and normal forces but I can't seem to find an equation to express the graph.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by stronger?  Stress to break the string or a larger stress to produce a given strain?

Comment: I guess I'm not really measuring the strength. More like the force required to extend it to a set distance. The hook in my picture is hooked up to a newton meter.

Comment: Strength of the rope or the braided-rope would generally be interpreted as the stress required to break the rope. You appear to be measuring the force required to produce a a given amount of strain, which will be something $like$ a Youngs Modulus. I suspect that in your set up, what you will end up measuring is the effect the force has through stretching the twists that make up the braid. (More precisely, reducing the twist per unit length) This, my intuition says, will suffer from hysteresis.

Comment: It does suffer from hysteresis to some extent so I keep the time it is strained to a minimum and change it between trials. Youngs Modulus seems very promising but seems to ignore the whole normal force / friction part that I think twisting would introduce. Thanks for the replies so far, they've been thought provoking.

Comment: Is it possible that I could  use the force value I get from Youngs Modulus resolve the component that would be applying the normal force and hence friction?

Comment: Would the cross-sectional area even change due to twist in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for an equation related to your problem but was unable to find one. There are a lot of variables involved, not simply the ones you mentioned. Braiding strings together to make the complete assembly stronger is dependent on keeping the binding force, due to the twisting, very consistent, otherwise you can introduce weak areas.

Also you need to allow for the method of manufacture of the string, is it composed of complete fibres running the entire length of the string? This is how synthetic ropes / strings are made, so braiding them together will not increase their existing strength. The string that appears in your picture looks like it is composed of natural fibers, and each natural fibre will be short, say less than 15 cm, so the string you have in your picture is already braided, even before you start, to knit together those short length.

If you still need  an equation, I guess it would relate the force that the string can withstand to the force, imposed by you, in creating the helical  pattern to bind the strings together. You would then need to resolve this helical force into two components, one perpendicular to the string length and the other parallel to the long axis of the string.

So, to sum up, you can't automatically assume braiding will increase strenght, it may instead decrease it.

Comment: Since after twist the strings are no longer parallel to the direction of extension. Does that mean a component of the force applied to is now acting perpendicular to extension and can be considered the normal force? The magnitude of that normal force would depend angle of where the fibers are and is?

Comment: I would say yes to your questions. My original  POV was that your question title is incorrect in a general  sense ( no offence:). As we both know, trying to find any equation relating to this is so far impossible. But I think from the comments above regarding hysteresis that you are studying this in more detail that I  thought (unfortunately that means your chances of finding an appropriate equation are even less, imo).  Most questions have a variety of level of detail/knowledge in the answers, so please consider my answer at the lower level : ), and the best of luck with a better one.

Comment: Two related links https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1iw1x7/if_i_cut_a_rope_into_4_pieces_and_braid_them/   and https://books.google.ie/books?id=hSjBPCvfKkYC&redir_esc=y   if they are of any help for background.